# radius server, mac address filter

Tags: sql, radius

I have a radius server and a SQL server on my Synology NAS.

On my network I have many switches asking to the radius server which VLAN is using for each Ethernet connection. Users and passes are requested on the Synology's local login system.

It works !

But I want to add a mac address filter.
I want to link user/pass to the physical machine to prevent the user from sharing their credentials.

I have a table with all mac addresses for each user.
An user can have more than one computer.

I want write my own radius rule, for example :

```
mac_check = "SELECT * from mac_addr_table WHERE Username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' AND MacAddr = '%Calling-Station-Id' ORDER BY ID"
```

Where can I add this line, how can I call it ?
Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mac-addr, is that meant to be Mac minus addr?

Comment: It is the name of the column which contains the mac address  of my client.

Comment: Then it needs to be delimited, as `"Mac-addr"`.

Comment: Ok it is a mistake. My question was about the execution of this check